# I am using FusionCharts. Now how to Implement FusionWidgets(AngularGauge) in iPAD?

Tags: ios

I am using FusionCharts. Now how to Implement FusionWidgets(AngularGauge) on iPAD? please provide XML also.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the tutorial that FusionCharts has on its blog - [Charts for iPhone and iPad apps using FusionCharts XT](http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2012/02/create-charts-for-iphone-and-ipad-apps-using-fusioncharts-xt/).

Sample code is provided with this tutorial.

Try this out and let us know if you get stuck anywhere..